# Android Studio Collapse definitions and methods

Tags: android-studio, editor

How can I collapse all definitions and methods within the Android Studio editor?

Visual Studio has that option on `Edit-->Outlining`, but I cannot find a similar feature in Android Studio. I am sure that this feature exists.

How can I access Android Studio's outlining feature?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android code folding the Switch block](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28533279/android-code-folding-the-switch-block)

Comment: I use "File => Settings => Editor => Gerneral => Code Folding => Collapse by default => Method bodies".  For me it's the best overview.

Answer (score 265, accepted):

It is called `Folding` in Android Studio.

First make sure it is enabled in config (it should be by default). Go to `File` -> `Settings`, then under the `IDE Settings` area find `Editor -> General -> Code Folding`, check the `Show code folding outline`.

To collapse/expand items use the `Code` -> `Folding` menu.

**Edit:**
To customize the keyboard shortcuts for these open Settings (`File` -> `Settings`) then select `Keymap` under `IDE Settings`. Now type `folding` into the search box (top right). Setup the keyboard shortcut for the various folding actions :)

Comment: Shortcut Expand: Cmd + '+'
Collapse: Cmd + '-'

Comment: shortcut expand all: shift + cmd + '+' (collapse all: shift + cmd + '-')

Comment: For Windows
shortcut expand: ctrl + '+' (collapse: ctrl + '-')
shortcut expand all: shift + ctrl + '+' (collapse all: shift + ctrl + '-')

Comment: In the version of Android Studio I have installed on my Mac, the Shortcut keys were Cmd + Shift + '+' to expand and Cmd + Shift + '-' to collapse.  This is slightly different than @Priebe's comment above.

Comment: what if i want to save that folding for future and adjust  whenever i re-open that file?

Answer (score 241):

For Windows:

```
  Minimize: CTRL + SHFT + '-'
  Expand:   CTRL + SHFT + '+'
```

For Mac:

```
  Minimize: COMM + SHFT + '-'
  Expand:   COMM + SHFT + '+'
```

Comment: This works with Linux as well. And use Cmd rather than Ctrl for Mac

Comment: thanks...  quick clear precise answer without the need to dig through remarks on how to make it even better by playing with shortcuts keys

Comment: so precise answer
I wish I could give you an award you like Reddit for such simple answer

Comment: if done to a class, it will fold the entire class down to just the class definition, with all methods and members completely hidden underneath it

Answer (score 56):

Here's screenshot for quick reference:

[image]

Comment: well done. people can pick up once again from this reference even if they forget shortcut keys some day

Answer (score 12):

**View -> Tool Windows -> Structure**

It's the equivalent to outline in eclipse. It gives you a far better overview of the class than folding.

Answer (score 11):

**my macbookpro**

`shift` + `cmd` + `¡`  *(character or button before delete)* Expand All

`shift` + `cmd` + `'` (character or button after zero) Collapse All

**windows**

`ctrl` + `shift` + `+` Expand All

`ctrl` + `shift` + `-` Collapse All

Answer (score 11):

**Windows:**
**Collapse:** ctrl + shift + Numpad-
**Expand:** ctrl + shift + Numpad+

Answer (score 10):

If you want turn off all collapsing you need uncheck all fields in the **Settings** > **Editor** > **General** > **Code Folding**

[image]

Also you can use hot keys

<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd> — expand code blocks

<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> — collapse code blocks

Answer (score 7):

This is valid for windows users:

1. Select a bunch of code, then press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>. This folds your block
2. Then to *remove* the folding, move to the first line where the fold starts. Don't select the code, just click in that first line, and again press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>

Answer (score 5):

**This work for me in Windows:**

minimize: <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd>

expand:   <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHFT</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd>

Comment: This is a copy of marlonpya's answer.

Answer (score 5):

The simplest way I know to collapse the methods is to use the command to **collapse all** and then the command to **expand recursively**

like this:  `crtl`+`shift`+`-` then `crtl`+`+`.

you can press `crtl`+`shift`+`-`, release `shift` then click `+` for convenience.

Answer (score 4):

> **Windows 10**

**`ctrl` + `shift` + `+`**   to Expand All

`ctrl` + `shift` + `-`       to Collapse All

Answer (score 4):

**What if i want to save that folding for future and adjust whenever i re-open that file?**

**Step 1:**
**We use custom folding**

Specify custom folding with comment *//region* for start and *//endregion* for end

```
//region anything that you want to write (you can even leave it blank)
...
//endregion
```

**Step 2:**

Go to Settings >> Editor >> General >> Code Folding >> Untick everything >> 'Tick Custom Folding Regions' & 'Tick Show Code Folding Outline' >> Apply >> Ok

Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sGuce.png

**Step 3:**

Restart Android Studio. You will see that the demarcated region has been collapsed.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some helpful shortcuts for folding stuff.

1. Select Some Code And Press Ctrl + Alt + T to auto Insert Region folding around the code
2. To Collapse Specific lines of Code, Select the code and Press Ctrl + .(dot/full stop) & Same for the reverse i.e. expand again
3. To collapse All method bodies/ if conditions etc etc Press Ctrl + Shift + -(hyphen)
4. To Expand All Press Ctrl + Shift + +(plus)

Answer (score 1):

(for windows)

If you are talking about `editor fold` just like `fcom` + `tab` in **netbeans**

`ctrl` + `alt`+ `t` 
and then add desired text in the desc block

Answer (score 1):

> New Android Studio come up with a lot of new functions. These are the commands you can use to fold different type of code.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue too. I figured out to click gear button where right top of project menu section. Then I unselected Show members option.

Answer (score 1):

For Mac you can use cmd + shift + -(hyphen/minus) to fold and to unfold every thing use cmd + shift + +

Answer (score 1):

For commenting methods separately, do code folding recursively
with ctrl  +  alt  +  -

Answer (score 0):

Optionally to collapse single method inside class rather than all methods @once use `cmd` and `-` on Mac
Cheers