# Android Studio collapse all shortcut for mac

Tags: android-studio, hotkeys

What would be the code folding shortcut on a mac for Android Studio?
Is there a default shortkey for this, or should we define our own?
It would be very handy to toggle, specially when working on a smaller screen.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

They call folding in android studio, I guess.

Shortcut expand: Cmd + '+' Collapse: Cmd + '-'
Shortcut expand all: shift + cmd + '+'

Comment: what about windows OS, I think Cmd = Ctrl

Answer (score 7):

For Windows users:

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> - to minimize

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> - to expand

from:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/28697392/606724