# Android code folding the Switch block

Tags: android, ide, folding

Under Android Studio 1.0.2 is there a way to fold the block of code for a Switch conditional statement? I could not find how to do it online or in File > Settings.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Select the code block and right click to choose fold code block (it "says" Ctrl-Shift-Period but  Ctrl-Shift-Period doesnt really do it....)

Comment: That does not fold the Switch block, it acts on the whole code. The Switch block does not have the - or + mini_icons to the left of its lines.

Comment: Whoops.  Typo on my part Its Ctrl-Shift-Period is supposed to do it

Comment: on mac it's cmd-shift-period

Answer (score 5):

To fold an arbitrary selected block

1. Select contiguous fragment of code in the editor.
2. On the main menu, choose Code|Folding|Fold Selection/Remove Region, or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Period</kbd>

Source: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/code-folding.html