# How to collapse all statements (including if else, forloop)?

Tags: android-studio, code-folding

I need to recursively collapse all methods and conditions in android studio.
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16527012/10561246) does not collepse if else block and for loops in side methods(recursively...)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jetbrains / Intellij keyboard shortcut to collapse all methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16526860/jetbrains-intellij-keyboard-shortcut-to-collapse-all-methods)

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16527012/10561246) is working but does not collepse nested if else loops and for loops inside methods.....

Comment: Loops aren't foldable and there is also a limitation for ifs according to https://stackoverflow.com/a/39423700/944070