# Android Studio: Code Folding turned off but not applying to imports

Tags: android-studio

I have turned off Code Folding using the [procedure described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18445044/android-studio-collapse-definitions-and-methods).

However, my imports are still folded away, hidden by an Ellipsis, as shown here:

[image: Imports hidden by ellipsis]

I really don't see the point of having code hidden away so that extra key presses or mouse clicks are required to see it.

How can I make Android Studio just show me everything?

Answer (score 2):

1. Launch Android Studio
2. Configure > Settings > Editor > General > Code Folding
3. Uncheck "Imports"

Comment: Doesn't work. I have already turned off the main Code Folding item "Show code folding outline."  Checking or unchecking the "Imports" sub-item makes no difference.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Android Studio Giraffe 2022.3.1 you can uncheck it on the following screen:

Preferences -> Editor -> General -> Code Folding