# How to shorten/hide code in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

After coming back to my project I noticed that the set.onclicklisteners had been shortened until clicked on, then it shows full code, just wondering if there is a quick way to do this as it could be quite handy to organize my code.

Example:

```
alongtimeBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()

    {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            alongtimeagomp.start();
        }
    });
```

was shortened to

[image]

I put this question into google and was shown how to hide code completely using ProGuard which is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio Collapse definitions and methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18445044/android-studio-collapse-definitions-and-methods)

Answer (score 8):

FYI, why your method is being shortened by Android Studio is because it's actually a [lambda expression](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java/lambda-expressions.html).

Apart from the shortcuts mentioned in other answers, there's also one weird trick you won't believe to neatly fold your code where you need it. You can define your custom regions of code, like so:

```
//region REGION NAME

someMethod();

someOtherMethod();

//endregion
```

Region name is of course totally up to you. After you define a region, IDE will be showing something like this:

[image]

where "Parsing JSON" is region name, and the green color denotes the region area. You can click "+" to expand it and "-" to collapse.

Answer (score 5):

You can simple use 
CTRL + SHFT + '-' for minimizing all the code
CTRL + SHFT + '+' for expanding all the code
 in android studio

Answer (score 2):

you can also  use **Ctrl + >**  for minimizing and **ctrl + >** to for expanding

Comment: So basically `ctrl + >` toggles the expanded/collapsed state of the code block?

Answer (score 0):

Select code and press CTRL+> for hide and press again to show
I hope it helps you