# Android Studio Folded Code-Blocks Expand After Return To Project

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, intellij-idea

Is there any way or plugin to save **folded code-blocks state** after exit android studio?
When I exit my project with folded code-blocks, then I return and open my project again I always find that these folded code-blocks were expanded!!
I use a lot of when-statements and multi-line comments etc..
So this problem is horrible for me!

Comment: Does the **File | Invalidate Caches & Restart** menu option help?

Comment: How can I use it?

Comment: Make sure you selected all necessary options under **File | Settings | Editor | General | Code Folding** (regions to be collapsed by default). Then perform the restart using the menu option I mentioned above so as to make sure any caching issues are out of the way.

Comment: Thanks, It help me but I want the code that I fold **any time any where** to still fold the next time I open the project like **Visual Studio Code**.

Comment: The solution has already been addressed here at this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18445044/android-studio-collapse-definitions-and-methods/70553069#70553069